# LINQ to XML result object not showing extension methods

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I have the code as below:

```
Dim xdTest As XDocument = XDocument.Load(GetXMLPath())
Dim objResult = From xe In xdTest.Elements("Some Element") _
                          Where xe.Element("strName").Value = strInput _
                          Select xe.Element("intValue").Value
objResult.
```

I cannot access any extension methods for objResult, like .ToList() or .First().  The file imports System.Linq and the project is targeted to .NET 3.5.

How do I get the extension methods back?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Import the System.Xml.Linq namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Assumed that GetXMLPath returns a valid path and strInput is a string. Replacing xdScenario with xdTest should allow intellisense to return.

Comment: Herp derp.  I made a mistake in my code above, it was actually supposed to be xdTest instead of xdScenario.  Fixed.